# Range.Copy (using Named Ranges) returns Formulas instead of Values

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to improve the performance of a couple of my Report Form which take several (5 to 10) seconds to complete loading the information (this is down from a previous time of 15 to 20 seconds). While doing research I found multiple threads discussing the processing time advantages of using the `Range.Copy Method` verses reading and writing one row of a range at a time.

My original code (one row at time) works perfectly except for the `Time Factor` and is as follows:

```
'Begin loading wsCost5Yr Worksheet
For frmYr = sYear To wbCurYear
  Debug.Print locID, frmYr
    wsSum.Cells(3, "Q") = frmYr 'Cell Q3 of the Summary Worksheet
    chartYrsCost.Cells(1, uClmn) = frmYr
        For uRow = 1 To 12
          'Get Gas Cost Values
            costG = sumCostG.Cells(uRow, 1).Value2
          'Get Electric cost
            costE = sumCostE.Cells(uRow, 1).Value2
            Debug.Print costG, costE
          'Convert Zero Values to Null
          If Not costE = 0 Then
                cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn) = costE
            Else
                cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn) = vbNullString
          End If
          If Not costG = 0 Then
                cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn) = costG
            Else
                cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn) = vbNullString
          End If
        Next uRow
    uClmn = uClmn + 1
Next frmYr
```

**ALL** ranges are properly `Declared` and `Set` during Initialization. The new code I am trying to implement, using the `Range.Copy` method is as follows:

```
'Begin loading wsCost5Yr Worksheet
For frmYr = sYear To wbCurYear
  Debug.Print locID, frmYr
    wsSum.Cells(3, "Q") = frmYr 'Cell Q3 of the Summary Worksheet
   
    chartYrsCost.Cells(1, uClmn) = frmYr
    sumCostG.copy cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(1, uClmn)
    sumCostE.copy cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(1, uClmn)
        For uRow = 1 To 12
          'Get Gas Cost Values
            costG = cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn).Value2
          'Get Electric cost
            costE = cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn).Value2
            Debug.Print costG, costE
          'Convert Zero Values to Null
          If Not costE = 0 Then cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn) = vbNullString

          If Not costG = 0 Then cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(uRow, uClmn) = vbNullString

        Next uRow
    uClmn = uClmn + 1
Next frmYr
```

Both ranges, `sumCostG` and `sumCostE`contain formulas that perform calculations as described above and and when I look ad the written contents of the destination cell I find `#REF!` errors with the actual cell contents as `=IF(A20="",#REF!,SUM(#REF!-A20))`!

I have read over 20 threads dealing with the `Range.Copy` method and the more I read the more confused I become.

Comment: You will want to do `destination.value = source.value` type or use `.pastespecial xlvalues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    sumCostG.copy cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(1, uClmn)
    sumCostE.copy cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(1, uClmn)
```

to this:

```
    sumCostG.copy 
    cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(1, uClmn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sumCostE.copy 
    cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(1, uClmn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Another option is `destination.value = source.value`:

```
    cmp5YrCostGdata.Cells(1, uClmn).Resize(sumCostG.Rows.Count-1,sumCostG.Columns.Count-1).Value = sumCostG.Value
    cmp5YrCostEdata.Cells(1, uClmn).Resize(sumCostE.Rows.Count-1,sumCostE.Columns.Count-1).Value = sumCostE.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Option 1 provided the solution to my issue and provided a marginal improvement in performance. Option 2 threw an "Application defined, Object defined" error '1004'. I suspect this error is due to the fact that sumCostG/E are single column ranges where the values in those ranges change based on the value of frmYr written to wsSum.Cells(3, "Q").  wsSum (the worksheet's CodeName) is a Summary  Report where the user may select a specific Property Location and the Annual Worksheet Year to retrieve data and perform the necessary calculations. Marked SOLVED!